# Continuous, differentiablee and continuous isomorphism, homomorphism

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, continuous-homomorphisms

I have very big confusions on Continuous, differentiable and continuous isomorphism, homomorphism of a FUNCTION. I am seriously looking a single example, which can explain the following clearly.

Given an example of some single function which is

1) Continuous 
2) Differentiable 
3) Continuous Isomorphism
4) Continuous Homomorphism

and explain how that function satisfies each of the above.

Many many thanks!
IFFl-edi

Comment: Can you think of a context, where all the above properties are meaningful? IOW can you think of a domain and a range such that it makes sense to talk whether a function is 1),2),3) and 4)? Describing one's own thoughts is expected from askers here, so it would be a good start to describe a context where the question makes sense.

Comment: And Welcome to Math.SE! The question in the previous comment is necessary, because otherwise it is difficult to gauge what kind of help will allow you to find an example yourself.

Answer (score 1):

1) Roughly, a **continous** function is any function you can draw without lifting your pencil. Examples are $\sin,\cos,x,e^x$. A non-example is $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } x \leq 0 \\ 0 & \text{ if } x < 0. \end{cases}$$

2) A **differentiable** function is any function without "kinks". Examples are all the above-mentioned functions. A non-example is the function $$f(x) = \mid x \mid = \begin{cases} x & \text{ if } x \leq 0 \\ -x & \text{ if } x < 0. \end{cases}$$

3) Formally, it is just a continous function that also has a continous inverse. Examples are $e^x$ (consideres as a function $\mathbb R \to (0,\infty)$ and $x \mapsto x$ (considered as a function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$). Non-examples are $\sin,\cos$ (these are not injective), depending on your choice of range and domain.

4) What is a homomorphism of topological spaces? Are you considering Lie groups?

**ADDED** Let $f:\mathbb R^{+} \to \mathbb R^+$ be defined by $f(x)=\frac 1x$.Then it is not hard to see that it is an homeomorphism. We can do this by checking that it has an inverse that is continous. But clearly $g(x) = \frac 1x$ from $\mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R^+$ is an inverse. It remains to see that they both are continous: but this follows from the more general fact that if $h$ is cont's, then $1/h$ is also cont's.

Comment: ! I am not considered lie groups.

Comment: ! The function L, where L = 1/x is continuous isomorphism in R+ to R? how and why? if you explain this part. I think problem is completed.

Comment: @iffl Does the added part clarify?